# Java Почему Spring - Tomcat закрывает все созданные соединения?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Я запускаю свое приложение `spring+tomcat` с такими параметрами:

```
-Xms256m 
-Xmx3048m 
-Dserver.port=3333 
-Dserver.tomcat.max-threads=30 
-Dserver.tomcat.max-connections=35 
-Dserver.tomcat.max-post-size=-1 
-Dserver.tomcat.connection-timeout=-1 
-Dserver.tomcat.keep-alive-timeout=-1 
-XX:+UseG1GC
```

Создаю 35 соединений через параметр `max-connections`, и выставляю время как `-1`, чтобы не закрывались соединения после простаивания.

После запуска хочу выполнить `get` запрос на получение данных (ну или любой другой запрос). Если запустить приложение, то через запросы можно получить доступ к данным и получить ответ от сервера, но если оставить сервер на 1-2 дня и заново обратиться к нему, то ничего не произойдет. До сервера не доходит запрос. Это я вижу через `Fiddler` и через само приложение.

Если посмотреть данные через `Progress Teleric Fiddler`, то можно увидеть такое сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На первой картинке видно, что `connection: close` хотя не ясно с чем это связано.

Исходя из параметров, которые задаются переда стартом приложения, соединения не должны закрываться, даже если происходит простаивание в течение долго времени.

Подскажите, с чем связана данная ситуация? Как можно сделать так, чтобы `tomcat` не закрывал соединения?

Comment: ¿Как вы установили, что это именно сервер закрывает соединение?

Comment: Это мое предположение. Все дело в том, что при старте все работает, но проходит определенное время простоя, может быть 1-2 дня и не удается подключиться к серверу. При этом в Fiddler вижу ошибку 502. Как думаете как можно решить это?

Comment: Во-первых, посмотрите порты, у вас в параметрах порт 3333, а ниже в логах 4444.

Comment: Также учитывайте, то что вы серверу ставите бесконечный кипэлайв, не значит что будет вечное соединение, это еще и от клиента зависит. Клиент может сделать одиночный запрос и сразу с запросом послать Connection: close. Потом вообще не понятно что вы хотите добиться, зачем вам нужно чтобы подключение висело 1-2 дня? Конкретно по проблеме что не можете сделать вызов к серверу, проверьте что сервер запущен, проверьте на каком порту, проверьте что пул подключений не забит, поставьте дефолтные настройки вместо -1.

Comment: `Исходя из параметров, которые задаются переда стартом приложения, соединения не должны закрываться, даже если происходит простаивание в течение долго времени` - именно. Если есть клиенты, которые не закрывают соединения, то через какое-то время все 35 доступных соединений исчерпаются, и новое соединение установить не удастся, что вы и наблюдаете. Так что решите, что вам важнее, чтоб соединения никогда по инициативе томката не закрывались (-1) или все же защититься от плохих клиентов, которые занимают соединения и не используют (поставьте не бесконечный таймаут).

Comment: Дело в том, что если поставить не бесконечный таймаут, а какое-то число, то tomcat по истечению этого времени закрывает соединение и заново новое не создает. 

Будто есть условно 35 подключений, значит 35 раз создается одно подключение, если уже 35 раз создавалось подключение, то 36 раз он не хочет создавать его. По взаимодействию с сервером ощущается именно такая картина.